# Subcaptionbox in tabu: wrong numbering of subfigures

Tags: subcaption, tabu

I'm am using the `tabu` environment inside figures to have some nice alignment for multi-panel figures. However, this seems to give me some problems with the numbering of the subfigures (the numbering of the subfigures in the second environments starts with c) rather than a), i.e. continues the counting from previous figures). 
Please see picture below.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S.: I am using Texlive 2018 and its seems to happen for lualatex and pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe,graphicx,tabu,subcaption,float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {XX}
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}&%
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}\\
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}&%
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}%
        \end{tabu}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg to move the figure to the top, so I can have a nicer screenshot which consumes less space :-). It's not used in the real code and also does not change the effect on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `caption` resp. `subcaption` package needs to track if a caption or sub-caption has already been typeset in the current figure or not. If neither of them has been typeset so far, and a `\caption` or `\subcaption(box)` comes up, the `figure` counter needs to be incremented and the `subfigure` counter needs to be reset.

Sounds easy, but why is this simple mechanism not working here? Because a `tabu` environment is typeset three times internally.

Try this one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe,graphicx,tabu,subcaption,float}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\showsubcaptionflag{%
  \show\ifcaption@subcaption}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {XX}
            \showsubcaptionflag
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}&%
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}\\
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}&%
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}%
        \end{tabu}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You will see that `\showsubcaptionflag` will be called three times, and at the 1st time the internal sub-caption flag is not set, but it is set at the 2nd and 3rd time (since `\subcaptionbox` has already appeared), confusing the `subcaption` package into not-incrementing the `figure` counter and not-resetting the `subfigure` counter on the 2rd and 3nd run of `tabu`.

The `tabu` package tries hard to avoid side-effects caused by typesetting the table internally three times, but it is not aware of the internal flags of the `subcaption` package and therefore is doomed to fail here.

Solution: I will see if the `tabu` package provides a hook for package authors where I can do the stuff needed for compatibility with the `caption` package. (It it does not there is little I can do, especially since the author of the `tabu` package is not making changes anymore.)

Workaround: Reset the internal flag of the `caption` package every time the `tabu` tabular is typeset:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe,graphicx,tabu,subcaption,float}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\clearsubcaptionflag{%
  \@ifundefined{caption@chgflag}{}{%
    \caption@clrflag{subcaption}}}
% Dirty Hack: The following line will reset the
% `subcaption` flag on every internal run of `tabu`:
\g@addto@macro\tabu@setstrategy{\noalign{\clearsubcaptionflag}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {XX}
%           \clearsubcaptionflag % no subcaptions so far
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}&%
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}\\
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}&%
            \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}%
        \end{tabu}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: I filled a bug report here: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/27

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer! As I have a lot of figures with `tabu`s inside, is there a fast work-around e.g. by patching the `tabu` environment with `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabu}{\clearsubcaptionflag}`? Would that be safe/recommendable?

Comment: @bonanza Using `\AtBeginEnvironment` does not work here, because the code placed here will only be used at the beginning of the environment and not at the beginning at the (internal) run of the `tabu` environment content. (Try it out for yourself.) I'm looking for a proper patch point inside the `tabu` package right now, please hold the line...

Comment: ...Basically `\AtBeginEnvironment` is like placing the extra code *before* each environment, and not *inside* each environment, but the latter one is what we need here.

Comment: @bonanza Give `\g@addto@macro\tabu@setstrategy{\clearsubcaptionflag}` a try. (This needs to be placed inside `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`. Will edit my answer right now...)

Comment: @Thanks but this seems to interfere with normal tabu tables like ` \begin{tabu} {XX}
  bla & blubb
  \tabucline{-}
  2 & 4
 \end{tabu}`. Which gives me "! Misplaced \noalign.
\tabucline ->\noalign 
                      {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \tabu@cline 
l.31  \end{tabu}"

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt, do you hope that the `tabu` package will be fixed? it has many more bugs (for example `m` specifier not work properly any more due to changes in `array`). as far as i know, package is not maintained ... is this changed now?

Comment: @Zarko According to the author of `tabu`, it's "completely unmaintained": https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/xRGJTC74uCI/jkNlDkpG5cMJ I haven't heard anything different.

Comment: @bonanza Even `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tabu} \begin{document} \begin{tabu} {XX} bla & blubb \tabucline{-} 2 & 4 \end{tabu} \end{document}` gives `! Misplaced \noalign`. If you give me an example code which does compile without my patch but does not compile with my patch, I will try to improve my patch.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt you are right, my mistake. I took the discussion to gitlab. I hope that fine with you.

Comment: @bonanza That's fine with me.

Comment: @bonanza Fixed with https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/e0e7867deeb291e445888fd1384003d4de55a874, so when using the upcoming version of the `caption` package the dirty work-around is not needed anymore. Please note that I changed the workaround in my answer so it won't clash with future versions of the caption package.

Comment: @bonanza Thanks for the feedback. If the current workaround is still making any problems, you could remove it and try using the new caption.sty instead: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/raw/3.3/tex/caption.sty

Comment: A new version (2018-09-12) containing the bugfix was uploaded to CTAN right now.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `subcaption` doesn't like `tabu` (and I'm on the same side).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,tabu,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {XX}
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} &
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}} \\
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} &
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tabu}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it is safe to add `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}` via `etoolbox` to the beginning of each `tabu` environment start, such as `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabu}{\setcounter{subfigure}{0}}` ?

Comment: @egreg Could you also tell, why `subcaption` doesnt do business with `tabu`?

Comment: @RaajaG Sorry, I'm investigating, but I'm not really willing to look in `tabu`.

Comment: @egreg Okay sure!